# Add Key to Dokku

Tags: digital-ocean, private-key, dokku

I am trying to add a key like this one:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEuwIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKUwggShAgEAAoIBAQCslQfgfW3L+/Kx
beM8LnJ2ocbX/YdS43ry69e5nmK2RM/GuJqRMZ0JrMfEtQ0FlKGxS9+cBhOV6Yt3
fCx8LcgWZY5mhpSrB4r90d5q93HrR/uVGGuu0QOf5+eq+YK2vUVCIer8Yxpg+wGf
4DyW/aWo6qriy7sPApAtuqiAkjLwKENVe9qsrXsNgG9+YTpgKXhQ4abTbSN55K0W
6TBNqA8MyKe3buPQ2GspjieotyZVGGBXASMKPLRuhuOEuRl2GbenYigfMoth5t3Q
8xQhphR88gcdiTdb1mvesB23DfHb5pPR+14hebH1AjbDEpxYSiNMGcQUa3yJ8b3H
0Z/6xIllAgMBAAECgf9Yffygmg+GKFBBrIJUsV3oB+cGp3gwI3asAP8XJup9NsT4
RFcom/0li0qrSc+WgQb3DH67fsXyIlhXQ/ZGCL5sVWNkPggQsyD2vZf/VLR1pVYF
bHZvnxX6h/RMJJUqgBi0C/fY9pQxt37IDhWFhk9hlnkCsT4tcOMFrhMV/MK7wsIO
dz+6FnLgscBL6ocugwsO8vP/VI9rP7BdtYx8YNqG1qOeh3oQkP4/jU5p1FkCrNrS
NldVOnzdftfpZ//DVMcjMrMU6rlBX9ChN5weapbyLjlZ/2qlvGJky3I05ifFB55B
VrIfTx0X8kdnRR71hz9fQq1NFfSIKQPSwLC3OnECgYEA7oruyXl9rxYFDLEIdXEg
gFFHlcN9sZNejMxRM1Y/oZs5C1tYjavllP3pHfEsZWzjI4b/XwHHCxlicY0/ggyz
rK9NY3lzDpyNgpFLGr+afrIjaXFI5jp1vq+sDy07h3Nbj4oUUggOdy2CqFEc9KWY
jMZbdqnZHxAou25RVyP/brasdfgsuTZV3X+dGLI55Jvmu+aefaiBCKZFyXjTDH2l
od4bM9/BFYvUI5X8UV8QZocPCHwsefqfw7apj1WOIJGZ6Tjw5mn1xEaBXnAXiAvf
AXIf9BWlDo7WjmUl6NWNIf7qJTXD8vELce8mKh6jHaQ/ayyloeOceXUMz+E8a0n/
RUXTuvUCgYAnrXpcjtXGCr6aRtQmXMPQNDTZB2Rf5ihi+RVEmcMJyXzqk64eGoqc
hsOA1H3S/RKm9SyDDBOkl/tU8e6vXheA0MPpmOj3dDjhj/NTJq23B0B2qH48tVqi
diwDdj2hoSGItan9nxNw5WQHRT6wvt6qA9Bw432W+iQcURQ8j2NMcQKBgGzk6W8l
jLPsdeVXVD29xgmTfOoc+IMQKuX5Kd0VvWCuedO1NrEFiig9gGMHnWsbtvqwxCZJ
yz+eycWUVa2t8NVID1urKHzh4rP2ZtNuyiK0Zys8CCIIjlVq2WPXgMsH5YF8/4Gp
XgL9qGHRJAhbY7bfICy5CSNgBin+g7uy5l3RAoGBAIIUHR66LjzVSCsvhlafuYrK
k4mRpGKMyEknat9SWCrmDY+gqkLzTOQx/EKaTvWD41UV6LSGFIp0y3WICvl/VlON
uimrsFTLOByhIVDdgOy1kHgzgIMiGhVYXQe04hFUNrSq0KMcDQ5q73LrktL3wnMS
hDVAh9SSDAe+xULorSPK
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Don't worry it has been created for the example.
I want to add it as an env variable. But in this key, the newline is important, so I was looking around and found that if you search for the env file, you can modify it directly.
I did that but every time I restart the app, the file erase all my env vars and only keep some that dokku makes.
Could anyone tell me why, or how I could add this key to my env vars.
The file I am modifying is this one: nano /home/dokku/chatbot-test/ENV

Thank you,

Jonathan Prieto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after two days trying to resolve this, I finally found out how.
First, you have to put a \n at the end of each line to represente the newline.
Second, you have to use a website as this one: [One Line Converter](https://lingojam.com/TexttoOneLine)

After that, when you read your env var in your project, you have to use reggex to convert your \n into a real newline with this:  `.replace(/\\n/gm, '\n')`

This resolved my issue perfectly.